why does firebase genkit stream back data as json string except for the last 2 chunks?
I am using firebase genkit w/ gemini pro 1.5 and streaming the response back to the client. Each chunk streaming back is a valid json string like the one below that i can parse. However, the last 2 chunks are bundled together as one stream, causing the parse to fail.
example chunk: {"index":0,"content":[{"text":"this is a test"}]} // valid json string
last 2 chunks: {"index":0,"content":[{"text":"this is a test"}]} {"index":0,"content":[{"text":""}]}
Why is that happening and what is best practice?
My current solution is to use try parse and if it fails, string split by "}{". But I am looking for a cleaner solution.
configureGenkit({
  plugins: [
    firebase(),
    vertexAI({ location: "us-central1" }),
    dotprompt(),
  ],
  logLevel: "debug",
  enableTracingAndMetrics: true,
});

const nonEmptyString = z.string().refine((value) => value.trim().length > 0, {
  message: "String cannot be empty",
});

// Define a schema for a non-empty array of non-empty strings
const nonEmptyArray = z.array(nonEmptyString).refine((arr) => arr.length > 0, {
  message: "Array cannot be empty",
});
        
export const carePlanGenerationFlow = onFlow(
      {
        name: "carePlanGenerationFlow",
        inputSchema: z.object({
          content: z.string(),
          sourceUrls: nonEmptyArray.optional(),
        }),
        outputSchema: z.any(),
        authPolicy: noAuth(),
      },
      async (promptData, streamingCallback) => {
        if (!streamingCallback) {
          throw new Error("this flow only works in streaming mode");
        }
    
        const planPrompt = await prompt("carePlan");
        let response =
          "Something went wrong and I am unable to generate the care plan.  " +
          "Please try again.";
    
        try {
          const llmResponse = await planPrompt.generate({
            input: {
              content: promptData.content,
              sourceUrls: promptData.sourceUrls,
            },
            streamingCallback,
          });
    
          response = llmResponse.text();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("error generating content: ", error);
          response = "Sorry I encountered an error processing your request.  " +
            " Please try submiting your request again.";
        }
    
        return { carePlanText: response };
      },
    );


Please edit the question to share your code so we can see more clearly what isn't working the way you expect. Ideally we should be able to reproduce the problem using the code you provide.  If you think there is an error with Firebase, then you should contact Firebase support directly to report the problem - we can't really help you resolve that.

I assume you are talking about the output you see from an HTTP call to a flow in streaming mode (with ?stream=true).
Flows stream data in JSONL format (https://jsonlines.org/examples/), so you should be seeing something like this:
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":"this is a test"}]}
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":""}]}

depending on the LLM you use (ex. try ollama/gemma) you might see something like this:
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":"this"}]}
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":" is"}]}
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":" a"}]}
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":" test"}]}

Different LLMs chunk output differently.
There should be a \n after each chunk (an no trailing \n after the final result) and the consumer of the flow stream is expected to handle decoding of the stream. If you use the stream from the HTTP response each chunk should be individually parsable, but if you're buffering the response then you will need to split it by \n

yes this is exactly what i'm referring to. I am streaming the chunks and parsing it no problem. However the last chunk contains 2 jsons in one string like this:
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":"this is a test"}]} {"index":0,"content":[{"text":""}]}
causing the parser to fail. Is that the expected behavior for the last chunk or a bug?

here's another example of the last chunk:
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":", address any concerns, and monitor progress. \n* Encourage the patient to schedule appointments with their primary care physician and other specialists as recommended. \n"}]}
{"index":0,"content":[{"text":""}]}
as you can see, parsing this will be an issue.

Certainly sounds like it could be a bug. Would appreciate any help to reproduce it (code sample if possible). Are you using flows server or cloud functions for firebase?

I added code sample. I am using firebase cloud functions. thx
